# Firebase Functions: How To Keep Json & env Files Safe?

Tags: firebase

I have a callable firebase function inside my 'functions' folder.
In the same folder, I also have json files with sensitive information and also api keys
stored inside my .env file which are required for my function.

I deploy everything to firebase using: `firebase deploy --only functions`, meaning my whole functions folder is on firebase.

My question is, how can I protect the data inside .env and the json files?

This particular function requires authentication to be accessible, but does it really protect my files?

[image]

Thanks for reading!

**Edit:**
It turns out there's a service called 'App Check' which allows to block users who shouldn't access the api:

```html
  if(context.app == undefined){
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      'failed-precondition',
      'The function must be called from an App Check verified app.'
    );
  }
```

Is it sufficient? Can authenticated users still somehow access the files?